# how to do template not matching using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements, xslt-1.0

I have an requirement in which I am processing the message based on the root element tag and for that I have created 3 different template match based on the root tag element. I was wondering how to process the message if the client is sending different message which is not matching the root tag element.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<process1 xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" languageCode="en-US">
    <Appdata>
        <Sender>
        </Sender>
        <Receiver>
        </Receiver>
        <CreationDateTime/>
    </Appdata>
</process1>
```

**2nd message:** Everything will be same except root tag will be `process2`, `process3`

**Code:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='proces1']">
        <operation>dosomthing</operation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='process2']">
        <operation>dosomthing2</operation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='process2']">
        <operation>blah blah</operation>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question here is I want to process message in case if it's not matching the 3 templates **process1,process2,process3**.

Can anyone please give advise how to achieve that?

Comment: Is the internal structure _within_ the root the same in all cases? If the input root element is `<xyz> .... </xyz>` do you know the structure of what is inside? Is it always the same as your example?  You can be pretty flexible in XSLT but you have to have _some_ knowledge of the document structure.

Comment: Thanks Jim. All the partner are using same standard schema so root tag can be different however inside elements will remain same. I just wanted to add another template in case they send wrong message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use `local-name()`. It's easy to declare and use the proper namespace, do it.

Secondly, just make a template that is less specific to catch any document element with a name that you did not anticipate (see the 4th template below):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:oagis="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10"
>
    <xsl:template match="/oagis:process1">
        <operation>dosomething1</operation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/oagis:process2">
        <operation>dosomething2</operation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/oagis:process3">
        <operation>dosomething3</operation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*" priority="0">
        <!-- any document element not mentioned above -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: If the first three templates all do the same, you can collapse them into one.

```
<xsl:template match="/oagis:process1|/oagis:process2|/oagis:process3">
    <operation>dosomething</operation>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, but I was wondering if we are using /*  don't you think it will choose that first? Or Can you please explain about /*

Comment: I was going to say *"because `/*` has a lower priority than `/oagis:process1`"*, but in fact it hasn't (without the slash `*` has a lower priority than `oagis:process1`, though). My mistake, the rules are here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict. When multiple matching templates have the same priority, XSLT breaks the tie and picks one that was defined last. So either you define the template that matches `/*` first - or you explicitly assign a low priority to it. I've changed my answer to do the latter.